# Making the options in a drop down list html element items in a javascript list?

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, drop-down-menu

```html
<html>
<body>
<?php
//student interface
$file = fopen("subject.csv","r");
$subjects = fgetcsv($file);
fclose($file);
//puts the csv file provided into a 2d array
$studentTable = array();
if (($handle = fopen("students.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
 while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
  $studentTable[] = $data;
 }  fclose($handle);
}
//creates list that will store list of girls emails
$usernames = array();
//runs through studentTable and appends emails to toEmail. 
for ($I = 0; $I < sizeof($studentTable); $I++){
       array_push($usernames, $studentTable[$I][0]);
  }  

?>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   
// Using PHP implode() function to turn the php list into a javascript list
var subjects = <?php echo '["' . implode('", "', $subjects) . '"]' ?>; 
var usernames = <?php echo '["' . implode('", "', $usernames) . '"]' ?>; 
var select = document.getElementById("usernames");
for(var i = 0; i < usernames.length; i++) {
    var opt = usernames[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
}​
var subchoice = [];
subchoice.push(document.getElementById("choice1"), document.getElementById("choice2"), document.getElementById("choice3"), document.getElementById("choice4"), document.getElementById("choice5"));
for(var x = 0; x < subchoice.length; x++) {
 for(var i = 0; i < subjects.length; i++) {
  var opt = subjects[i];
  var el = document.createElement("option");
  el.textContent = opt;
  el.value = opt;
  subchoice[x].appendChild(el);
 }
}​
var six = [];
six = subjects;
six.push("null");
var select = document.getElementById("choice6");
for(var i = 0; i < six.length; i++) {
    var opt = six[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
}​
</script> 
<h2> Select your subjects! </h2>
<form>
<p> Select your name </p>
<select id='usernames' name='usernames'>
<option>Choose a username</option>
</select>
<p> Select your 1st choice subject </p>
 <select id='choice1' name='choice1'>
 <option>Choose a subject</option>
 </select>
<p> Select your 2nd choice subject </p>
 <select  id='choice2' name='choice2'>
 <option>Choose a subject</option>
 </select>
<p> Select your 3rd choice subject </p>
 <select id='choice3' name='choice3'>
 <option>Choose a subject</option>
 </select>
<p> Select your 4th choice subject </p>
 <select  id='choice4' name='choice4'>
 <option>Choose a subject</option>
 </select>
<p> Select your 5th choice subject </p>
 <select id='choice5' name='choice5' >
 <option>Choose a subject</option>
 </select>
<p> Select your 6th choice subject (none is an option) </p>
 <select id='choice6' name='choice6'>
 <option>Choose a subject</option>
 </select>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I can't get anything to appear in the drop down tabs. The drop down should be the items in either the subject or username list. However, nothing happens even though I think I have coded it correctly. It gives me this error message: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'" I have looked for this extra token but can not seem to find it, please help!

Comment: Whatever 'it' is that's telling you there's an unexpected token will also tell you what line it's on. If you view souce you'll see where it is.

Comment: **Don't mix JS & PHP.** Your `unexpected` item doesn't exists in this part of code, Ctrl+F can't find it. Study how to read errors and [how to debug JS code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Comment: I am actually able to turn the php array into a js array. The issue lies within this statement  ------- for(var i = 0; i < usernames.length; i++) {
    var opt = usernames[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
}​ --- I don't know why these statements are giving errors, as I know the javascript arrays are populated correctly. An issue with select.appendChild(el) maybe? why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<html>
<body>
<?php
//student interface
$file = fopen("subject.csv","r");
$subjects = fgetcsv($file);
fclose($file);
//puts the csv file provided into a 2d array
$studentTable = array();
if (($handle = fopen("students.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
 while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
  $studentTable[] = $data;
 }  fclose($handle);
}
//creates list that will store list of girls emails
$usernames = array();
//runs through studentTable and appends emails to toEmail. 
for ($I = 0; $I < sizeof($studentTable); $I++){
       array_push($usernames, $studentTable[$I][0]);
  }  

?>
<h2> Select your subjects! </h2>
<form method="POST" action='handlestudents.php'>
<p> Select your name </p>
<select id='userN' name='userN'>
        <option selected="selected">Choose one</option>
        <?php
        // Iterating through the product array
        foreach($usernames as $item){
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo strtolower($item); ?>"><?php echo $item; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
</select>
<p> Select your 1st choice subject </p>
 <select id='choice1' name='choice1'>
 <option selected="selected" >Choose a subject</option>
        <?php   
        // Iterating through the product array
        foreach($subjects as $item){
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo strtolower($item); ?>"><?php echo $item; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
 </select>
<p> Select your 2nd choice subject </p>
 <select  id='choice2' name='choice2'>
  <option selected="selected" >Choose a subject</option>
        <?php   
        // Iterating through the product array
        foreach($subjects as $item){
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo strtolower($item); ?>"><?php echo $item; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
 </select>
<p> Select your 3rd choice subject </p>
 <select id='choice3' name='choice3'>
  <option selected="selected" >Choose a subject</option>
        <?php   
        // Iterating through the product array
        foreach($subjects as $item){
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo strtolower($item); ?>"><?php echo $item; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
 </select>
<p> Select your 4th choice subject </p>
 <select  id='choice4' name='choice4'>
  <option selected="selected" >Choose a subject</option>
        <?php   
        // Iterating through the product array
        foreach($subjects as $item){
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo strtolower($item); ?>"><?php echo $item; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
 </select>
<p> Select your 5th choice subject </p>
 <select id='choice5' name='choice5' >
  <option selected="selected" >Choose a subject</option>
        <?php   
        // Iterating through the product array
        foreach($subjects as $item){
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo strtolower($item); ?>"><?php echo $item; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
 </select>
<p> Select your 6th choice subject (none is an option) </p>
 <select id='choice6' name='choice6'>
  <option selected="selected" >Choose a subject</option>
        <?php
        // Iterating through the product array
        foreach($subjects as $item){
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo strtolower($item); ?>"><?php echo $item; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
  <option value = ""> None </option>
 </select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```